# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting below said collation error since I have moved from a desktop machine to a laptop. My database has hundreds of stored procedures, so any solution like overriding some queries or fix collation for a column is not possible for me.

"Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation"

My problem is not unique and I have searched for this quite a lot, but solutions available suggest me to override queries with some code which is not feasible. Please suggest some solution that may avoid this collation thing.

I have tried this to alter my database collation.

```
ALTER DATABASE testDB  
COLLATE French_CI_AI ;  
GO
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Just use the following syntax to collate on the fly when joining tables with different collations. I integrate systems, so I have to do this a lot.

```
select * from [Product] p join [category] c 
on  
c.[Name] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
= 
p.[Name] collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: For anyone that can do it on the fly

Comment: Thanks Master Styles, for your response but this is not going to help me as my problem is spread in around 600+ stored procedures with 100+ tables.

Comment: @MasterStyles i want to change whole db collation. it's possible?

Comment: @coderwill It is possible, but very dangerous.  For example, switching from case-insensitive to case-sensitive, and vice versa, will impact every = and <> operation in all your queries touching textual data.

Answer (score 7):

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE PRATAP
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS ;
GO

--Verify the collation setting.
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N' PRATAP ';
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the server collation setup. We need to change the server collation setup.

.\Setup.exe /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=DESKTOP-QUAN3NS\admin  /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS-- collation you want

Once you can run this command on
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\SQL2019
using Powershell.

Answer (score -2):

jUST ADD this line -> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS in your joinings. Thats it :)
https://premkt.blogspot.my/2016/12/error-cannot-resolve-collation-conflict.html