# Issue in procedure (resolve the collation conflict)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written a stored procedure like below lines of code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_AgentLinceseInfo_Fetch]
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BrList') IS NOT NULL 
       DROP TABLE #BrList

    CREATE TABLE #BrList
    (
        AgentCode nvarchar(max)
        ,BrokerName nvarchar(max)
        ,LicenceID bigint
        ,LicenceNumber nvarchar(max)
        ,EffectiveDate datetime
        ,ExpirationDate datetime
        ,State nvarchar(max)
    );

    INSERT INTO #BrList
        SELECT 
            a.AgentCode AS BrokerCode, 
            sy.BrokerName, 
            L.Licence, L.LicenceNumber,
            DateIssued AS EffectiveDate,
            L.ExpirationDate,
            J.JurisdictionX AS State
        FROM
            tbAgent AS a
        INNER JOIN 
            tbLicence L ON L.AgentId = a.Agent
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            (SELECT Jurisdiction, JurisdictionX 
             FROM tbJurisdiction) AS j ON j.Jurisdiction =
                       (CASE 
                           WHEN ISNULL(L.Jurisdiction, '0') = '0' 
                              THEN a.PhysicalAddressState
                              ELSE L.Jurisdiction
                        END)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN  
           (SELECT 
                SystemUser, (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) AS BrokerName 
            FROM tbSystemUser) AS sy ON sy.SystemUser = a.SystemUser

    SELECT * FROM #BrList

    SELECT 
        t.*, p.ProductX, p.ProductCode 
    FROM
        tbCompanyAgent ca
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT  
             AgentCode, BrokerName, 
             LicenceID, LicenceNumber,
             EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, [State] 
         FROM #BrList) AS t ON t.LicenceNumber = ca.LicenceNumber
    INNER JOIN 
        tbProduct p ON p.Product = ca.ProductId

    DROP TABLE  #BrList
END
```

When we execute this procedure, it throws error message

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict
>   Cannot resolve the collation
>   conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
>   "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393207/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and

Comment: check out your tempdb collation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have two different collations in comparing columns 
You should not have two different collation in columns when you want to compare them.

**Example:**

Consider the following query

```
SELECT 1
WHERE  'a' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Which will throw error stating

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 1 Cannot resolve the collation
>   conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

It can resolved by explictly making the `collation` same in both `LHS` and `RHS`

```
SELECT 1
WHERE  'a' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = 'a' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
```

Try updating your query like this

```
SELECT t.*,
       p.ProductX,
       p.ProductCode
FROM   tbCompanyAgent ca
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT AgentCode,
                               BrokerName,
                               LicenceID,
                               LicenceNumber,
                               EffectiveDate,
                               ExpirationDate,
                               [State]
                        FROM   #BrList) AS t
                    ON t.LicenceNumber COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = ca.LicenceNumber COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
       INNER JOIN tbProduct p
               ON p.Product COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = ca.ProductId COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: Where should I write this procedure.

Comment: @Nida First identify out of two select queries which select query is throwing error

Answer (score -1):

jUST ADD this line -> SQL_Latin1_Gener**strong text**al_CP1_CI_AS in your joinings. Thats it :)

https://premkt.blogspot.my/2016/12/error-cannot-resolve-collation-conflict.html