# "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i am new to SQL queries

My query is

```
ALTER TABLE ValidIBAN NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_ValidIBAN_Countries
UPDATE t 
 SET t.CountryID = s.Corrected
from #TempNewCountryID s,Countries t
where 
s.Existing = t.CountryID
```

but after running this query i am getting

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Error Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL\_Latin1\_General\_CP1\_CI\_AS" and "Latin1\_General\_CI\_AI" in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393207/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Comment: Seems like you should to do a table definition overview. If you need to add COLLATE clauses to your queries, your table definitions are probably inconsistent.

Comment: You really should get in the habit of using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 9):

Depends on which logic is required (Accent sensitive or insensitive), use COLLATE on both sides of your equal sign: `WHERE s.Existing COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI = t.CountryID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`

Comment: Is there a way to use this at the top of the statement once? It does seem to be good practice using this in every equal sign to me because I need to use this multiple times then.

Comment: No, as far as I know you can not use it only once: SQL allows so much flexibility (and room for bad practice ;-) ) that you can define different collations per column...

Answer (score 0):

If you update collate on table, or database(if needed), even in the server(if needed), then you never such an error.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI;
```

I think it is better to update collate on the table rather than using it on queries.